# Invalid argument supplied for foreach with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, foreach

I'm getting `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error in my view after publishing a post and the code i use for looping in my controller is this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
$post = Post::find($id);
$categories = Category::all();
$cats = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
$cats[$category->id] = $category->name;
}

$tags = Tag::all();
$tags2 = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
$tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
}

return view('admin.posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats)->withTags($tags2);
}
```

this is the only part i handle loops in my postcontroller edit section. And I know the issue is from `Tags` loop because when I remove the tags code in my view other part will show up correctly.

Oh and this is the loop i use in my view:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">{{ $post->title }}</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><img src="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" class="img-responsive" /></p>
                    <p>{!! $post->body !!}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="tags">
                    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                        <span class="label label-default">{{ $tag }}</span>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('sidebar')
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> Post Info</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <label>URL:</label>
                    <p><a href="{{ url('blog/'.$post->slug) }}">{{ url('blog/'.$post->slug) }}</a></p>
                </dl>

                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <label>Created On:</label>
                    <p>{{ date('M j, Y h:ia', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</p>
                </dl>

                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <label>Last Update:</label>
                    <p>{{ date('M j, Y h:ia', strtotime($post->updated_at)) }}</p>
                </dl>

                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <label>Posted In:</label>
                    <p>{{ $post->category->name }}</p>
                </dl>

                <hr/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Html::linkRoute('posts.edit', 'Edit', array($post->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-block')) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::open(['route' =>['posts.destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}

                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block']) !!}

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                {!! Html::linkRoute('posts.index', '<< Back to Posts', [], array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block')) !!}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.4

- Post updated view!

Comment: What is `$post->tags` supposed to return? Try `dd($post->tags)` in the controller code; or else use `tinker`.

Comment: @linuxartisan $post->tags will get tags related to the post from postcontroller which i put the code above.   and it comes from store function which is this `$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);`.     PS: i used dd() and turns error of Undefined variable.

Comment: Let's see the relation `tags` defined in the `Post` model.

Comment: @linuxartisan post model:   `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function category() {

     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tags() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get **tags** via **post** so Try this...

```
<div class="tags">
                @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                    <span class="label label-default">{{ $tag }}</span>
                @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: tags

Comment: i changed with dev suggestion in up and also with my own code in top on this page in both way same error.

Comment: Keep your code in controller just change code  in blade

Comment: can you provide full code after update with my code?

Comment: Yes just change your view code not controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return view('admin.posts.edit')->with("post",$post)->with("categories",$cats)->with("tags",$tags2);
```

and at view

```
<div class="tags">
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <span class="label label-default">{{ $tag->name }}</span>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: tags

Answer (score 0):

1. in your table if your primary key name if not **id** you have to mention in your relationship [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

2.for your post has one category so you can show this into your view like this

```
{{ $post->category->name }}
```

if you get result you can use it. but seems you need tag key and value pair so use this methods

```
$tags = Tag::where('post_id',$post->id)->groupBy('id')->get();
```

or try your way

```
$tags = Tag::all();
$tags2 = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
$tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
}
```

return view('admin.posts.edit',compact($post,$tags2,$cats));
in your view try this

```
@foreach ($tags as $key => $tag)
    <span class="label label-default">{{ $tag }}</span>
@endforeach
```